# JavaScript arrays braces vs brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the difference between each of the following array definitions.

```
var myArray = [];
var myArray = {};
var myArray = new Array();
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The first and third are equivalent and create a new array. The second creates a new empty object, not an array.

```
var myArray = []; //create a new array
var myArray = {}; //creates **a new empty object**
var myArray = new Array(); //create a new array
```

Comment: How do we access values of the object.

Comment: With brackets or dot notation: `myObject["someValue"]` or `myObject.someValue` . The empty object created by `{}` will of course not have those properties, but you can assign to them in the same way: `myObject.someValue = "hello!"`

Comment: In this particular case 1 and 3 have the same effect. Sometimes, however, they behave differently. For example, if `var a = new Array(5)` and `var b = [5]`, then `a` ≠ `b` (since `a.length` = 5 while `b.length` = 1, `a[0]` is `undefined` while `b[0]` is 5, and so on.)

Comment: is `var a;` and `var a = {};` the same?

Answer (score 31):

`var myObject = {};` is equivalent to var `myObject = new Object();`

So, the second example is not an `Array` but a general `Object`.

This can get confusing as `Array` is a class and `Object` is a class - more precisely `Array` is a sub-class of `Object`. So, by and large, `Object` semantics are applicable to an `Array`:

```
var o = [];
o.push('element1');
o.push('element2');
o['property1'] = 'property value';  // define a custom property.
console.log(o.property1);
console.log(o.length);  // Outputs '2' as we've only push()'ed two elements onto the Array
```

Comment: where is property1 stored. Is it not in the array

Comment: @Pinkie: This is getting confusing now: *Arrays are objects too*. By doing `o['property1'] = 'property value'`, you are not actually adding an element to the array, but setting a property of the *array object*. Confused? I told ya ;) In JavaScript, basically everything is an object. Other objects, like `Array`, `RegExp`,... extend the basic object with further functionality. A plain, empty object is created it with the curly brackets `plain_obj = {}`.