# Difference in Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript arrays braces vs brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129544/javascript-arrays-braces-vs-brackets)

I have a simple question that I can't find an answer to with Google.
What is the difference between

```
var foo = { };
```

and

```
var bar = [ ];
```

An example would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo = {}` is not an array, but an object (created using object literals, `{}`).

`bar = []` is an array, which inherit various methods from the Array constructor. An array also has various properties, such as `.length`.

**EDIT** *(regarding comment)*:
The `a` property of an object can be accessed through `foo.a` or `foo["a"]`.
Looping through the properties of the object should be done using a `for( .. in .. )` loop.

```
var foo = {"a":true, "b":false};
for(var prop_name in foo){
    alert(prop_name + " - " + foo[prop_name]);
}
```

This code will show two alert messages:

```
a - true
b - false
```

Comment: but i've seen object being used like this: `foo = {"a":true, "b":false};`. Would it then be possible to see, if "a" is in "foo"?

Comment: @GregaMenih: Sure: `'a' in foo`.

Comment: It's important to note that it's still an object, not an array.

Comment: Great help, noted. One question only now: To see if 'a' is in foo, I would do `"a" in foo`, then what would I do to see if 'a' is NOT in foo?

Comment: @GregaMenih Use a `!` (logical NOT, negation): `!("a" in foo)`. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference#Operators_and_other_keywords