# Difference between var = {} and var = []?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objects vs arrays in Javascript for key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688097/objects-vs-arrays-in-javascript-for-key-value-pairs)

I have a variable in JavaScript which I am using like a *hash*. I can initialize it like:

```
var selected = [];
```

or

```
var selected = {};
```

and it does the same exact thing. I'm using it like this for example:

```
selected["one"] = 1;

if (selected["one"] == 1) console.log("one is selected"); 
// result: one is selected

if (selected["two"] != 1) console.log("two is not selected");
// result: two is not selected

selected["one"] = 0;

if (selected["one"] != 1) console.log("one is no longer selected");
// result: one is no longer selected
```

Is there really a difference? Is one an *object* and the other an *array* ? If so, when should I expect to run into problems. Ie., what is the difference between the two in their usage, and why would you chose one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Objects vs arrays in Javascript for key/value pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688097), [What is the difference between an array and an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205), [JavaScript arrays braces vs brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129544)

Comment: This happens because arrays in Javascript are objects too. So you can assign stuff to the array object's slots just like a plain object.

Comment: Don't confuse array-like syntax with arrays. For example, in Javascript `selected["one"]` is equivalent to `selected.one` (the former supports arbitrary strings as keys, the latter alpha-numeric ones).

Comment: Even if this is technically really just a duplicate of the difference of array and objects, for someone who doesn't know (or keeps on forgetting it) that {} is an object and [] is an array, this is a different question. Kinda like 2 is different from 'two'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`[]` is an array, `{}` is an object. An array is a type of object intended to be only assigned numeric keys.

While you can in theory use them interchangably, look what happens when you JSON-ify them:

```
var tmp = []; // or: var tmp = {}
tmp.one = 1;
JSON.stringify(tmp);

// array:
'[]'

// object:
'{"one":1}'
```

Answer (score 4):

An Array (`[]`) is a *kind of* Object (`{}`).  The key differences are:

- Arrays have a magic `length` property that is equal to the highest-set numeric key (plus one):

  ```
  var a = [];
  a[100] = 0;
  a.length; // is 101

  var o = {};
  o[100] = 0;
  o.length; // is undefined
  ```
- An Array's `toString` method prints out the values of numeric keys:

  ```
  var a = [];
  a[0] = 5;
  a[1] = 6;
  a[2] = 7;
  a.toString(); // "[5,6,7]"

  var o = {};
  o[0] = 5;
  o[1] = 6;
  o[2] = 7;
  o.toString(); // "[object Object]"
  ```
- Arrays have lots of specific functions for processing records:

  ```
  > Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)
  ["join", "toLocaleString", "sort", "some", "lastIndexOf", "splice", "map",
   "constructor", "every", "unshift", "shift", "indexOf", "pop", "forEach", "reverse",
   "reduce", "slice", "concat", "filter", "toString", "reduceRight", "push", "length"]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, `{}` is an empty object and `[]` is an empty array. Note that an array *is* a kind of object, optimized to handle a list of values, but, like any Javascript object, it can accept other attributes like `"one"` or `"two"` — which is how it can support methods like `myArray.push(1)`: `push` is an attribute of all arrays. In fact, you can even say `myArray["push"] = someOtherFunction` to override `push` without any trouble. Arrays, like all Javascript objects, support arbitrary key-value assignments.

Ultimately, though, it has to do with behind-the-scenes performance. If you're looking to store a sequential list of values, the array will handle it much better and offer some helpful attributes like `push`, `shift`, `length`, etc. — plus, future developers will actually know what you're doing. If you're looking to just store key-value pairs, the object is the way to go, since it's not bogged down by all that extra weight.

In short, while they both support key-value pairs, they're very different behind the scenes. Don't worry too much about it and use whichever lends itself better to the job at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Using `{}` is an object, which is the basis for every complex type in Javascript. The reason you can treat an array like an object is because in Javascript an array *is* an object (but not the other way around).

The square brackets in Javascript are the way you access an object's attributes, much like the `.` notation in C, Java, Python, etc. It just so happens that arrays have values at attribute 0, 1, 2, etc. Arrays also have a whole bunch of other built-in attributes like `length`, `shift`, `push`, etc.

This is an oversimplification for sure, however it's an easy way to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

An Array is an Object, but an Object is not (always) an Array.
An Array has methods and properties not present in every object
Example

```
[].length //0
{}.length //undefined
typeof []['slice'] //function
typeof {}['slice'] //undefined
```

If you use an array as a hashmap and try to use as a key something already present you will get into trouble

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is for arrays and `{}` is for plain objects. Note that an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is an object with a number of [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) and properties that allow to model lists (e.g. push, slice, ...).

As pointed out in the MDN documentation, [you shouldn't use an array as an associative array](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), i.e. arrays are not to be used as hash tables.

Answer (score -1):

The first is an `array`, the second is a `literal object`:

```
var a = {};
a.SomeProperty = 1;

console.log(a.SomeProperty);

var b = [];
b['SomeProperty'] = 2;

console.log(b['SomeProperty']);
```

This will output `1` and `2` in the console logs.

`For hashing, use an array` (**WRONG**), thanks for the comment.

Comment: -1 for "For hashing, use an array"

Comment: Why is that? I'm actually interested in your answer, since that what I was doing until now.

Comment: An array is best used for numerically indexed storage (`var a = []; a[0] = 1;`). If you want a hash, an array has nothing more to offer than a simple object (`var a = {}; a['prop'] = 1;`) - and it can even have drawbacks you might not expect (like the JSON representation in Kolink's answer).