# What does a variable directly followed by empty curly braces mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Going through the Eloquent Javascript book where I encountered something I haven't seen before.

In the code snippet below the variable 'map' is followed by empty curly braces. Can someone please explain what this means? Does this do anything tot he function that follows.

Also, can someone explain what map[event] = phi; does exactly? I take it this map refers to the variable 'map' we declared in the first line...

```
var map = {};
function storePhi (event, phi) {
  map[event] = phi;
}

storePhi("pizza", 0.069);
```

Comment: `map = {}` is declaring an object. `map[event] = phi` is adding a property to `map` where the name is equal to the value of `event` and `phi` is the associated value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript arrays braces vs brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129544/javascript-arrays-braces-vs-brackets)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done even basic research? A quick google search for "curly braces in Javascript" answers your question...

Comment: I did indeed do research Luke Taylor. I hadn't yet seen an empty object being declared. I was probably overthinking the significance of it. I now see that this specific example shows that the object is 'filled' in the next steps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `{}` represents an empty `object`.

`map[event] = phi` will add (or overwrite) a property on the `map` object with the name `event` and assign it to a value of `phi`. This way, you can do `map.EVENT_NAME` to get the value of phi for that event.

After performing `storePhi("pizza", 0.069);`, map will look like this:

```
console.log(map);
map = {
  pizza: 0.069
}

console.log(map.pizza);
map.pizza = 0.069
```

Comment: That's a great explanation for what turns out to be a really simple concept. I now understand that the empty object is 'filled' by storePhi() and how the properties and their value are created!

Comment: Cool. It might also be worth mentioning that `map.pizza` and `map["pizza"]` are two ways to say the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It means the variable is a dictionary that stores key value pairs. The subscript or the value within the [] brackets is the key and the value on the right side is the value.

Comment: I am pretty sure this does not answer the question

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith It's not strictly accurate to refer to it as a dictionary but this answer is correct.

Comment: @MikeC That is why I said "pretty sure", I am a bit confused by the analogy... With no examples, it makes it hard to follow.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Well, dictionary is [a well-established synonym for associative array.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)