# Trying to understand Javascript code that looks like object functioning as map

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and came across some Javascript code that looks something like the code below. It seems like `carArrays` object is being turned into a map just by virtue of assigning an array to `carArrays[car1.year]`. So I have a number of questions about this code.

1. What javascript rules allow you to do this?
2. I thought `[]` means array. If carArrays is now a map why are square brackets being used to index into it?
3. Is my interpretation correct about carArrays becoming a map? Or is this still considered an object with keys '1999' and '2005'?

My code:

```
function car( make, model, year){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

let car1 = new car('bmw', '3series', 1999);
let car2 = new car('ford', 'crownvic', 1999);
let car3 = new car('honda', 'accord', 1999);

let car4 = new car('bentley', '5', 2005);
let car5 = new car('chevy', 'silverado', 2005);
let car6 = new car('toyota', 'rav4', 2005);

let carArrays = {};
carArrays[car1.year] = [car1, car2, car3];
carArrays[car4.year] = [car4, car5, car6];

console.log(carArrays);
```

Comment: `I thought [] means array.` Sure, but `[]` is nowhere in the code you posted. `{}` is an object literal. `obj[someVar]` is bracket notation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: The square brackets notation on an object detones that is assigning or accessing a property in the object. In this case, you're creating a new property with the same name that `car1.year` would have (i.e. 1999) and assigning the values or car1, car2, car3 inside an array. Same for the other property.

Comment: carArrays[car1.year], first value of "car1.year" would be calulated, then it would assigned as a key to object carArrays and then rght hand side expression would be evaluated and assigned to this key of object

Comment: why the negative vote?? it is a question...as I stated I'm trying to learn javascript.

Comment: Are you confused about what `let carArrays = {};` is *actually* doing? It's not necessarily the easiest thing to pick up on if you're new to javascript.

Comment: not sure. What is confusing me is it looks like carArrays is functioning as a hash map. For example i can retrieve the first array by doing this: carArrays[1999]. That looks like a hash map. But I never did carArrays = new map(). What indicated to Javascript that carArrays was supposed to be a hash map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. What javascript rules allow you to do this?

`carArrays` is an object (as denoted by [`{}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Creating_objects)). This means it will have key-value pairs, where a key points to a particular value. However, you need to define what those key-value pairs will be. At the moment your object is empty, but, you can add key-value pairs to it in multiple ways:

*Directly*:

```
let carArrays = {
  "myKey": ["element1", "element2"]
}
```

Using [*dot-notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation):

```
let carArrays = {};
carArrays.myKey = ["element1", "element2"];
```

... or using [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
let carArrays = {};
carArrays["myKey"] = ["element1", "element2"];
```

All of the above ways of adding key-value pairs do the same thing - they add a key of `"myKey"` to the `carArrays` object with a value being an array of elements (`["element1", "element2"]`).

The thing to note about *bracket notation* is that it allows you to pass a key into the object to define it, so something like so is also valid:

```
let carArrays = {};
let theKey = "myKey";
carArrays[theKey] = ["element1", "element2"]
```

So, when you do your code:

```
let carArrays = {};
carArrays[car1.year] = [car1, car2, car3];
```

... you're using *bracket notation* to set a *key* for `carArrays` to be that of the value stored at `car1.year` (ie: 1999) and its value to point to an array of car elements (`[car1, car2, car3]`).

> 2. I thought [] means array. If `carArrays` is now a map why are square brackets being used to index into it?

As discussed above, it is not only used for indexing arrays, but it is also used to get/set values on objects. This is known as [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation). If you delve further into Javascript you'll uncover that arrays are in fact just objects, so when you use `[]` on an array, you're really using bracket notation again.

> 3. Is my interpretation correct about carArrays becoming a map? Or is this still considered an object with keys '1999' and '2005'?

Javascript has two main ways of representing data as a key-value pair relationship. One way is using the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class, and another way is by using an object `{}`. Both `new Map` and `{}` allow you to keep a data-structure which stores key-value pair relationships. In your code you're using an object (`{}`), not a `Map`. Moreover, in the past, we didn't always have the `Map` class in Javascript as it is only a relatively new addition (to ES6) and so, objects (`{}`) were mainly used instead. To see the main differences between a `Map` and an Object, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18541990/5648954) or [this comparison from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared).

Thus, for your code, it is still considered an object with keys '1999' and '2005' (as you are not creating a `new Map()` object anywhere in your code, but instead are using a regular object (`{}`) to store your key-value pairs.)

Comment: OK this answer really sheds some light, mostly answers my first 2 questions. As regards the 3rd question what I mean by map is very straightforward. I mean hash map. Both in Java and Javascript (most languages I would suspect) there is a map implementation of the (hash) map data structure in some library. In Java it is HashMap or HashTable. In javascript it is `Map` I believe that does the same thing. So it looks like javascript objects are a kind of map by default in Javascript with key/value pairs.

Comment: @swiftie Hi, I've updated my answer to help clarify your third question. Essentially a `Map` and an object `{}` are very similar in what they do (they do have their differences though)

Comment: The [Objects and maps compared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared) section on MDN might be a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, `carArrays` is not a map.

For proper definition of a map see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Specifically, you initialize a map using an array or object whose elements are key-value pairs like this:

```
let myMap = new Map([[ 1, 'one' ],[ 2, 'two' ]]);
```

On the other hand, `car1`, `car2`, `car3`, `car4`, `car5`, and `car6` are all objects. `carArrays` is an **object** of arrays and not an array.
The code:

```
carArrays[car1.year] = [car1, car2, car3];
```

simply creates a new key or property of `1999` in `carArrays` and assigns this key an array containing the three objects: `car1, car2, and car3`

You can visualize the `carArrays` object like this:

```
{'1999': 
    [
        {
            'make':'bmw', 
            'model':'3series', 
            'year':1999
        },
        {
            'make':'ford', 
            'model':'crownvic', 
            'year':1999
        },
        {
            'make':'honda', 
            'model':'accord', 
            'year':1999
        }
    ],
 '2005':
    [
        {
            'make':'bentley', 
            'model':'5', 
            'year':2005
        },
        {
            'make':'chevy', 
            'model':'silverado', 
            'year':2005
        },
        {
            'make':'toyota', 
            'model':'rav4', 
            'year':2005
        }
    ]
}
```

However, objects and maps have some similarities and differences. You can also check them on the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared)

Also look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129544/javascript-arrays-braces-vs-brackets) for added clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code and see, `console.log` will return this:

```
{
  "1999": [
    {
      "make": "bmw",
      "model": "3series",
      "year": 1999
    },
    {
      "make": "ford",
      "model": "crownvic",
      "year": 1999
    },
    {
      "make": "honda",
      "model": "accord",
      "year": 1999
    }
  ],
  "2005": [
    {
      "make": "bentley",
      "model": "5",
      "year": 2005
    },
    {
      "make": "chevy",
      "model": "silverado",
      "year": 2005
    },
    {
      "make": "toyota",
      "model": "rav4",
      "year": 2005
    }
  ]
}
```

The curly braces represent objects, while the square brackets represent arrays. so this code:

```
let carArrays = {};
carArrays[car1.year] = [car1, car2, car3];
carArrays[car4.year] = [car4, car5, car6];
```

creates a new object, `carArrays`, and creates two key value pairs. The keys are years, while the values are an array of car objects.

```js
function car( make, model, year){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

let car1 = new car('bmw', '3series', 1999);
let car2 = new car('ford', 'crownvic', 1999);
let car3 = new car('honda', 'accord', 1999);

let car4 = new car('bentley', '5', 2005);
let car5 = new car('chevy', 'silverado', 2005);
let car6 = new car('toyota', 'rav4', 2005);

let carArrays = {};
carArrays[car1.year] = [car1, car2, car3];
carArrays[car4.year] = [car4, car5, car6];

console.log(carArrays);
```

Comment: This much I knew. I ran the code myself before posting. What I don't understand is what is happening. What javascript rules are allowing this. This is not intuitive behavior if you come from a Java or C++ background. carArrays looks like it is being turned into a map. Is that the case or am I mistinterpretting??

Comment: @swiftie That's how you assign keys to arrays and objects. `$arr["myKey"] = [];`. JavaScript doesn't have the concept of maps.

Comment: oh right....Javascript doesn't but there is `Map` class defined somewhere (JS library) that that does maps. but I see your point... the language itself doesn't have it.

Comment: @symlink JavaScript does have an in implementation for maps. Check my answer or see (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)