# defining a model with array of object using sequelize for postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using `sequelize` for building and migrating models to postgres. I am trying to add my attributes in an array of objects like this:

```
approvals: [ { id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER }, isApproved: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true, }, approvedById: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, }, }, ],
```

and it's returning this error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

Full `createTable()` call:

```
await queryInterface.createTable("leaves", {
          id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
          emp_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          },
          from: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
          },
          to: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
          },
          desc: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
          approvals: [
            {
              id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
              isApproved: {
                type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: true,
              },
              approvedById: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              },
            },
          ],
          createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
          updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your question properly and add some explanatory text. In the current state, it is completely unclear what you need help with.

Comment: sir am using sequelize for building and migrating models to the postgres, at that am trying to add my attributes an array of objects like this  approvals: [ { id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER }, isApproved: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true, }, approvedById: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, }, }, ], and its returning this error ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

Comment: Try creating your attributes as an object instead of an array, cmp. `createTable` function documentation (https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-createTable). There should not be any brackets (`[`) in there, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129544/javascript-arrays-braces-vs-brackets